# How to call function under function on controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

Need to call some function from mu function indexAction on same controller so I do that :

```
class Admin_GeneController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

public function indexAction() {
    $GetJobResult=$ws;

        $this->blockcustomer
    }

    function blockcustomerAction(){ 
            $GetJobResult->property;
     // I have Notice: Undefined variable: $GetJobResult
        }
}
```

How can I call this function `blockcustomer`, and I have this Error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: $GetJobResult

Comment: Why do you need to do this?? Try this `blockcustomerAction()`.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** create new functions inside a function, but you can return a function from inside another function. So your code is invalid.

```
class Admin_GeneController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->blockCustomer();
    } 

    // if you won't access a function from url don't add Action at the end.
    private function blockCustomer() {
        // code 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create public and private function in controller itself and call them inside Actions.

**Private Function**

```
class Admin_GeneController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    //Create private functions in this way (do not add Action suffix)
    private function _blockCustomer(){ 
        //definition 
    }
    public function indexAction() {
        //Call function in this way
        $this->_blockCustomer();
    }
}
```

**Public Function**

```
class Admin_GeneController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    //Create public functions in this way (do not add Action suffix)
    public function blockCustomer(){ 
        //definition 
    }
    public function indexAction() {
        //Call function in this way
        $this->blockCustomer();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

You cannot access variable like this, you have to pass variable while calling `blockcustomer` function in below way.

```
class Admin_GeneController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $GetJobResult=$ws;
        $this->blockcustomer($GetJobResult);
    }

    function blockcustomer($GetJobResult){ 
        echo $GetJobResult;
    }
}
```

**Using class variables:**

```
class Admin_GeneController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    private $GetJobResult;
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->GetJobResult=$ws;
        $this->blockcustomer();
    }

    function blockcustomer(){ 
        echo $this->GetJobResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but when i call this funtion i have notice undefined varaibale declared on index and i used on bloccustomer thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your latest code which you're using? So that i can understand the problem clearly.

Comment: no it's not parameter passed by function it's varaibale declared and i have much variables declared

Comment: You have declared variables in Action hence it wont be accessible inside another function. try defining them globally after class declaration. or you can pass an array as well if you have too many variables.

Comment: i do that global $ var;  after declare class and i have this error syntax error ,unexpected 'global',expecting 'function'

Comment: In Zend you need not to write global if you need to access variable in a particular class only. Refer edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to the variable that is out of the scope. So you need to define a global variable.